# How do I print the average of the last three values in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the **code**:

```
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 6):  
    print(my_list [i] + " " + my_list [i+1] + " - " + my_list [i+2] + " - " + my_list [i+3] + " , " + my_list [i+4] + " , " + my_list [i+5])
```

So this code takes a file, and prints 6 lines from the file into a single line, in this format:

```
Marilyn Munro - 65783234 - 66, 77, 89
Johnny Lang - 83492753 - 45, 65, 45
```

I want the code to average out those last three numbers so the output while goes from this:

```
James Hanniburg - 359372932 - 50, 75, 100
```

To this:

```
James Hanniburg - 359372932 - 81.25 #81.25 being the average of 50, 75, and 100, assuming 100 is worth 50%, and 50 and 75 are each worth 25%.
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the third value is worth 50% while the other two are each worth 25%.

Any clues??

Comment: You need to add the three numbers and divide by three. Do it on a separate line to make your code more readable (it doesn't currently fit on the screen). Oh, and Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [ask], and what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. modify your code to:

```
for i in range(0, len(ml), 6): 
    weighted_avg = sum([int(ml[i+3]), int(ml[i+4]), 2*int(ml[i+5])]) / 4
    print(ml[i] + " " + ml[i+1] + " - " + ml[i+2] + " - " + str(weighted_avg))
```

This calculates the weighted average by [summing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) the `int`-converted values (multiplying the double-counting last one by `2`) and dividing the result by `4`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I forgot to mention that the third value is worth 50% of the grade, while the other two are each worth 25% of the grade. Any help with this? I'm trying to figure it out myself, but something;s not working.

Comment: @antoniomunro I amended the answer to account for the weighted average.

Comment: which is 3rd value?

Comment: @Rarblack That is quite obvious from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
(Value weights has been added.)

```
my_list = ['James', 'Hanniburg', 359372932, 50, 75, 100] # just input

a, b, c, d, e, f = my_list
print('{0} {1} - {2} - {3}'.format(a,b,c,((d*0.25+e*0.25+f*0.5)/3)))
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
James Hanniburg - 359372932 - 22.916666666666668
```

You can also ***import mean from statistics***:

```
my_list = ['James', 'Hanniburg', 359372932, 50, 75, 100]
from statistics import mean 
a, b, c, *d = my_list
print('{0} {1} - {2} - {3}'.format(a,b,c,mean(d)))
```

Comment: Do not forget to accept an answer to the question and upvote it so others can find it easily and the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in range(0, len(my_list), 6):
        print("{} {} - {} - {}".format(my_list[i], my_list[i+1], my_list[i+2],((my_list[i+3]+my_list[4])*0.25+my_list[5]*0.5)/3))
```